# spring batch 3 ItemReader reading CSV file data only one time

Tags: java, spring-batch

Hi I am new to Spring Batch and I referred [this link](http://www.concretepage.com/spring-batch-3/spring-batch-3-annotation-example-using-mysql-gradle) to run the sample program.

I wanted to insert the large amount of CSV file data into MySQL database and through the example I am able to execute it fine with limited number of lines of CSV data.

But when I inserted more number of lines into CSV file and execute the batch program it was not inserting any data in other words it was not reading the file itself and not even showing any error/exception(s). I think I need to configure `ItemReader` to read for more than one time.

Following is the BatchConfiguration.java code

```
 @Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<Student> reader() {
        FlatFileItemReader<Student> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<Student>();
        reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("student-data.csv"));
        reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<Student>() {{
            setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {{
                setNames(new String[] {"stdId", "subMarkOne", "subMarkTwo" });
            }});
            setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Student>() {{
                setTargetType(Student.class);
            }});
        }});
        return reader;
    }


    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Marksheet> writer(DataSource dataSource) {
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<Marksheet> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<Marksheet>();
        writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<Marksheet>());
        writer.setSql("INSERT INTO marksheet (studentId,totalMark) VALUES (:stdId,:totalSubMark)");
        writer.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<Student, Marksheet> processor() {
        return new StudentItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job createMarkSheet(JobBuilderFactory jobs, Step step) {
        return jobs.get("createMarkSheet")
                .flow(step)
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, ItemReader<Student> reader,
            ItemWriter<Marksheet> writer, ItemProcessor<Student, Marksheet> processor) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
                .<Student, Marksheet> chunk(5)
                .reader(reader)
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/concretepage");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("root123");
        return dataSource;
    }
```

main class to run

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
        List<Marksheet> result = ctx.getBean(JdbcTemplate.class).query("select studentId,totalMark FROM marksheet", 
                new RowMapper<Marksheet>() {
            @Override
            public Marksheet mapRow(ResultSet rs, int row) throws SQLException {
                return new Marksheet(rs.getString(1), Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(2)));
            }
        });
        System.out.println("Number of Record:"+result.size());
    }
}
```

process class

```
public class StudentItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Student, Marksheet> {

    @Override
    public Marksheet process(final Student student) throws Exception {
        int totalMark = student.getSubMarkOne()+student.getSubMarkTwo();
        System.out.println("student id:"+student.getStdId() +" and Total mark:"+ totalMark);
        Marksheet marksheet = new Marksheet(student.getStdId(), totalMark);
        return marksheet;
    }

}
```

Any help will be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Not sure how this can work even with a smaller file, as you are not invoking Spring Batch anywhere in your main method..

Comment: @EnableAutoConfiguration tells Spring Boot to start adding beans based on classpath settings, other beans, and various property settings

Comment: How many lines you meant by **limited number of lines** and how many for **more number of lines** ? It doesn't seem logical that reader will work for few records and will not work for few more records unless its getting stuck somewhere in reading a large file and not completing.

Comment: Let us consider a CSV file have 6 lines of data and I will start the Spring Batch program  to insert it into Database it works fine then process will stops. After this if I change the CSV file by adding additional data and wanted to reflect the same data into database using strong Batch then it is not reading the modified CSV. If I look into the logs it says CSV file is read before and no modifications are present!